# Create Java method from a string?

Tags: java

Is it possible in Java, to declare a method with a string instead of an identifier?

For example can I do something like the following:

```
class Car{

     new Method("getFoo", {
          return 1+1;
     });
}

//Use it
Car car = new Car();
car.getFoo();
```

EDIT: I am adding a Purpose WHY I need this. In order to not hardcode method names when using Jersey and its UriBuilder, which requires a method name:
https://jsr311.dev.java.net/nonav/releases/1.1/javax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder.html

See path() method with signature:

```
 public abstract UriBuilder path(java.lang.Class resource,
                            java.lang.String method)
                     throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
```

So then I may just use string constants and not worry that the method name will ever be different from the string that I am passing to the path() method.

I hope my question is clear, if not - let me know and I can clarify it.

Comment: What are you ultimately trying to accomplish with the solutions to your 2 recent questions?

Comment: I believe you could use reflection to achieve that - but why would you want to? Do you want to generate classes dynamically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible in the way you described.

The closest thing is probably the [asm](http://asm.ow2.org/doc/tutorial-asm-2.0.html) library to create java bytecode.

Answer (score 1):

As per the purpose, why don't you just have a single method and let it act/behave differently depending on the caller and the parameters?

Comment: That is what I am currently doing. I have the same method, say "getFoo" in 5 different classes, and then I just pas the string "getFoo" to the UriBuilder. The problem is that if any of the method names change in the future, to say "getBar" - my string "getFoo" will still be passed to UriBuilder which will try to do reflection on it - and come up empty handed.

Comment: @drozzy Sounds like you should be declaring getFoo in an interface and having your 5 classes implement it?

Comment: Thanks, but I actually came up with a solution - I will only use Path annotations on classes and not methods. That way I will not have to refer to method names ever.

Answer (score 0):

It's indeed not great to have the method name as string in the code, but if feel the usage of reflection from your side and from jax-rs side should compensate so that this does not happen.

Let me clarify. I guess you are using `UriBuilder` because you want to expose a service, or something similar. If you reflect on the class and list the method, then pass their name in `UriBuilder`, which also reflect on the class, the method is never explicitly mentioned in the source.

I'm not familiar with jax-rs though, and without knowing more about what you exactly try to achieve (your edit does provide a bit more information, but does not explain the end goal you have in mind), I don't know if that makes sense. But it could be a track to follow.

Answer (score 0):

If you can consider using another language on the JVM, [Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/ExpandoMetaClass) can do that.